what is the best (as in tape efficiency) tape blocksize (using tar) when moving a tar'ed file to tape?
I have a number of large (300GB+) tar'ed files of pictures, movies and other backups.  I have LTO 3,4,5 tape drives.  LTO4 is 800GB native capacity yet two of the files, one 391,065,600KB and the other 143,296,800KB, won't fit on one 800GB tape.  The combined size of those two tar files is 534,359,400KB, calculated by expanding to bytes, adding and dividing by 1024.  That should easily fit on a 800GB tape except if the blocksize is set wrong.  Given it was one large file, I set the blocking to -b 1024 and they didn't fit. I use -b 1024 almost all the time as it is easy to remember. I read where the default tar blocksize is 512 on disk. It takes a while to back these up so I'd like to get it right this next time.  By the way, I use tape for longevity as well as having these in a "go bag" as I live in NorCal where fires are always possible. The files sit on ZFS mirrored drives.
Thanks
Jerry

What exact type of tapes do you use (manufacturer, tape type/name, model name)? What kind of tape drive do you use? What commands do you use to write on tape?

How are you writing the files to tape?

drives are LTO5 in a 2 drive by 24 slot library.  The tar files were created using defaults like:  tar -cvf /filename /infilename

The common minimal block size for LTO is 64K. Using smaller sizes may decrease performance - throughput and usable capacity.
Block sizes up to 512K may be set but don't usually increase throughput (depending on the exact drive model and possibly firmware version); usable capacity very slightly increases with larger blocks.
Essentially, when writing large files (e.g. tar'ed) to tape a large block size is reasonable. In doubt use 64K or 128K.
Make sure you can read back the tape. I haven't had issues with block size incompatibilities for ages but I test this all the same.

are you saying -b 64k or -b = 64k/512?  I generally use -b1024

You weren't totally clear that you refer entirely to tar. tar -b specifies the block size in multiples of 512, so -b 1024 actually means 512KiB.
